# Login to Office 365 using Protractor to access Angularized website

Tags: angularjs, protractor, office365

I am new to Protractor automation tool.
I am trying to automate an angular website which requires Office 365 login which is a non-angular page.

```
// spec.js
describe('Shoppingjoe Demo App', function() {
    browser.driver.get('https://console-test-sj.azurewebsites.net/shoppingjoe/controlpanel/home');
    var signin_usernameTextbox = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cred_userid_inputtext'));
    var signin_passwordTextbox = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cred_password_inputtext'));
    var signin_signinBtn = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cred_sign_in_button'));

    it('Login', function() {
        signin_usernameTextbox.sendKeys("user.name@domain.com");
        signin_passwordTextbox.sendKeys("password");
        signin_signinBtn.click();
    });

    it('should have a title', function() {
    //Title of Angularized website
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Shoppingjoe | Dashboard');
   });

  });
```

But the issue is, after entering `Username` Office 365 gets navigated to ask account type i.e "Work account" or "Personal account", for which Protractor is not able to access the element.

EDITED:
When I start the test, it launches
[image]

and after entering username
[image]

Any idea to get pass through this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it on an Office Portal, I just tried it on my own and I can get this

```
.tile_name_padding
```

Can you supply a screenshot (blur out stuff) of the window you are trying to access ?

Worst case scenario you can always use an external piece of code to click on that element.(RobotJs)

Also, if you are new to e2e, this might help you http://selectorgadget.com/

---

Edit :

Hey Ashish, I made a gamble and used that exact same login screen where i got

```
.title_name_padding

element(By.css('.title_name_padding'));
```

from, so can you see if that CSS selector is working for you ?

What does it say when you use it ?

If that fails you could try this

```
element(By.css('.[name]_[domain]_[com/eu/org]'));
```

So john@domain.com

```
element(By.css('.john_domain_com'));
```

Warning : I am currently not able to test these selectors, but they are supplied by the tool I linked [ http://selectorgadget.com/ ] and that has never failed me so far.

Comment: I have edited my question above with the screenshots, let me know if you need more details

Comment: Hey Anish, I eddited my post